# How do I stop the Adobe Flash Player updates from installing themselves?

Tags: adobe-flash, application-autoupdate

The Adobe Flash Player 11.0 update keeps installing itself on my HTC Desire. At over 17 MB that pushes me into the "Low space" zone and then my gmail stops refreshing etc... which is a disaster.

Now while I can go into Settings -> Applications and can uninstall the update (which leaves me with the stock version of the Flash Player which is fine for me), a couple hours later Flash reinstalls itself again. Not only is this annoying but it also cost me a lot of bandwidth.

Is there any way I can disable updates for this default application?

Comment: I urge you to do the flash player updates. Adobe flash player has a long history of security bugs. Not updating this often used web technology could compromise your security and therefore your system.

Comment: Yes that is a good point. Plus performance improvements. Have you tried moving Apps to the SD card to make more space? I don't think this is an option for all versions of Android but it might work for you.

Comment: @Flow: Thanks, I appreciate the warning. However I use my phone way more for checking Twitter and Gmail than webbrowsing so it's much more important to me that those work. If I had to forego web browsing because of the resulting security risk, that might be acceptable.

Comment: @bendemes Yes, I have moved as much as possible to the SD card and I've got a 16GB SD card. However I continue to be plagued by App Storage space problems. It's really the only complaint I have with the HTC Desire. I see nothing in the new phones that makes me want to upgrade except that the constant space problems on my Desire are a major annoyance. This Flash Player update is just the most recent problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to configure auto update via the market place. Open the market place go to my apps and find Adobe Flash Player and untick the "Allow automatic updating" box.

Comment: One problem I find with this is, I can no longer use "Update All" button.

Comment: I don't think unticking automatic updating should stop you using Update All. You can't use update all for any Apps that have changed there permissions requirements otherwise it should still work fine.

Comment: @bendemes When I search for "adobe flash player" on my phone it doesn't show up in the Android Market App. I then searched for it on Chrome on my PC, found Flash Player 11, signed in and tried to send it to my device and it says that it's not compatible with my device. Currently it's uninstalled but it seems to wait for the most inopportune time and then start downloading itself again when I'm on expensive 3G.

Comment: Once it had reinstalled itself I found it in the market and was able to deselect the "Allow automatic updating" option. So far it hasn't reinstalled itself since then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AS per [How to hide updates from market?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14421/how-to-hide-updates-from-market) you can detach the app from market using Titanium Backup. Long press the app and click detach from market. But bear in mind that this feature is available only in donate version of the app.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to see if any of the other suggests work for me first but if they don't then I will try this. I'm just hesitant to install another app (Titanium Backup) but if nothing else works then I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with my D1 Droid and simply uninstalled it. The YouTube ap picks up 99% of what I would use the flash player for anyway.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It's a totally reasonable creative solution. +1

Comment: @trlovejoy I have uninstalled it many times. The problem is that it keeps reinstalling itself and because it's a "stock app" that came bundled with my phone I haven't yet been able to find a way to disable this.

Comment: Try rooting your phone, then you can remove flash.