# How to hide updates from market?

Tags: google-play-store

I have an app that has updates that reduce the functionality of the app. Is it possible to hide the updates so that I can use the "update all" feature, or update all apps from the list without worrying about the app? I've backed it up with Titanium Backup so I'll be able to restore it but that's a bit of a hassle. Also, the constant "New updates available" notifications are a pain in the.... neck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of update notifications for a given app in Google Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58021/how-to-get-rid-of-update-notifications-for-a-given-app-in-google-play-store)

Comment: Sorry! That other question has more updated answers so I voted to close this one. By the way, why not consider merging both the pages?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Long press on the app in Titanium and choose "Detach from Market".

Answer (score 2):

Without root:

1. install [Appbrain App Market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps)
2. visit the [Appbrain Website](http://www.appbrain.com/) and sign in with your Google account
3. start the Appbrain App, sync your installed apps
4. start the Playstore App and deactivate all update checks

Now to check for updates, you can use the Appbrain app. This gives you, a.o., the possibility to...

- skip an update for a given app (but only one -- get reminded when a newer update is available)
- skip ***all*** updates for a given app (i.e. never be reminded/informed of any updates for this app

Additionally recommended: [AppMonster Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.think_android.appmanagerpro). Automatically creates backups of any app installed/updated. So if something breaks with an update, simply install the previous version -- and then in the Appbrain app, decide to skip this specific version. Or if you notice too late that an update removed functionality: same procedure, but in the Appbrain app decide to never update this app again.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread. And I understand that Ti Backup used to work for detaching an app from Play Store. But I also understand that this works no longer. For those who are interested, I have created an app that does a pretty good job of this. It is called [Hide Updates In Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whitedavidp.hideupdatesinplaystore&hl=en). There is a video showing the app at work. Thanks