# Manual Update: Exclude a certain apps from notifications

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

I have an application with a manual update available. I do not want to update it (I prefer the older one).

In the previous Google Market app (it changed, sorry I do not remember older version number) it was possible to exclude the app from further notifications.

With the current Google Market app I'm not able to do it anymore, and I always have the "You have 1 SW update available" notification on top screen (I have auto-update feature set).

How can I configure the Google Market app not to bother about that app anymore?
(or at least until further updates, in the future).

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Possibly related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14421/how-to-hide-updates-from-market

Answer (score 1):

There's no real solution -- but depending on how much this annoys you, a work-around is available:

1. install [AppBrain App Market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps). You can think of this app as an "alternate frontend" to the Google Playstore (and yes, it is no stand-alone market, as all updates/installs are re-routed to the Playstore-App).
2. log-in to the [Appbrain Website](http://www.appbrain.com/) with your browser and your Google-Account to initialize your account with Appbrain
3. now login with the Appbrain App you installed, and synchronize your installed apps.
4. Appbrain now shows you available updates to your apps. You can run them in a batch, or one by one, or can *decide one by one* whether you want to *skip just this update*, or *skip this (and all future) updates to this app* -- so it will not annoy you with updates you are not interested in.
5. start the Playstore App again, go to your apps list, open the settings, disable all update checks, updates, etc., and close it again.

Now the original Playstore won't ever notify you about *any* update whatsoever. Instead, you use the Appbrain App for updates. When looking for some new app, you can chose to use either of them. You might also decide to install the [AppBrain Ad Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.detector) along, and then probably will use the Appbrain App only -- as it helps you avoiding apps with excessive ads.