# How to exclude a program from being presented as program to update

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates

I have an Archos 101 tablet which has Google maps installed.

I cannot uninstall Google maps but since I don't need it on my tablet I don't update it.

However, it is constantly being presented in the list of apps with 'new update available.

Can I somehow exclude this app ?

I have not rooted my device and are running Android 2.2

Comment: Related question, rooted solution: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14421/how-to-hide-updates-from-market

Comment: @onik: I don't want to root my device simply bacause my knowledge of it is not large enough to make sure I don't do anything wrong.

Comment: @Edelcom Out of curiosity: Why don't you want the Maps update?

Comment: @Flow: It is a tablet without SIM car which I only use at home. I don't need to look up addresses or the likes on my tablet (I use my phone or the PC to do that). It is a rather large program ( which U unfortunately cannot uninstall ). I don't want to make it even larger with updates I don't use. Memory in my Archos is not that large to waste it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see around this is to uninstall Google Maps and the only way to remove built in apps is to be rooted and either use a 3rd part app or use ADB and uninstall the app yourself. There's no way of "excluding" an app from updates unless you simply uninstall it.

Comment: I don't want to root my devices until I know enough of the system to make sure I don't screw things up.

Answer (score 0):

If you meanwhile changed your mind concerning rooting your device (you had a full year to get to *know enough of the system to make sure [you] don't screw things up.* ;), next to un-installation there're some more options available using e.g. [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup):

- freeze (i.e. disable) Maps. This way it becomes "unavailable" on the device (and thus would no longer be updated, if you have a recent version of the *Google Playstore* on the device) -- but could be "unfrozen/re-enabled" any time.
- detach it from "market" (yeah, old term). This would leave the app available and useable, while telling Google Play it's not installed. Not installed → no updates.