# Is it possible to permanently supress app updates?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide updates from market?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14421/how-to-hide-updates-from-market)

I've been using a certain app for some time now, but according to the many 1-star reviews the latest "update" has got, it breaks compatibility with Tasker, which is not something I want.

Is there a way to at least temporarily remove the regular update notifications I receive, or stop the app appearing at the top of my update list every time?

Using Nexus S with official 4.0.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Titanium backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) for this purpose.

However you'll need root access for this to work.

From [this](http://matrixrewriter.com/wiki/tiki-index.php?page=TB+-+Technical+FAQ) Titanium backup wiki:

> **Can I tell the Market that I do not want to update a specific app?**
>
> Yes. Just long-click on an app in the Titanium Backup list and hit
> "Detach from Market".

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not rooted, but this may be a good reason to make the jump!

Comment: One of the good reasons :)